# Redirect http to https except one directory

Tags: .htaccess, yii

I have a problem, I tried the all options.

I want redirect all website http to https except one directory, this directory is intranet :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(intranet)
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(intranet)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

but now the all website show http and it doesn 't redirect to the https .

Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rule  is redirecting all requests except /intranet back to http because of the negitive Rewritecondition, remove the **!** char from your 2nd rule.
Try :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(intranet)
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(intranet)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Alternativly you could try this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} =http
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(intranet)
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} =https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(intranet)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Yes , but it doesn't redirect to https the main page and show http in the main page

Comment: Yes, you can see in www.naturaselection.com, I need this main page redirect to  https://www.naturaselection.com

Comment: it is very strange , now this link http ://www.naturaselection.com/intranet/ redirect to the error 404 and I need this link dd https ://www.naturaselection.com/intranet/ transformed into this http ://www.naturaselection.com/intranet/

Answer (score 0):

Use the rule only one time like this,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^intranet
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```